# How to fit the text to the camera view ? Some text is out of the camera bounds

Tags: 3d-view, camera, text-object

Half of the first T on the left and half of the Y on the right are out of the camera view. I tried to reduce the Focal Length value and it did the work, I just wonder if this is the right solution ?

[image: Part of the text is outside]

This screenshot is after changed the Focal Length value to 43 :

[image: Focal Length value is set to 43]

Comment: Have you tried moving the camera?

Comment: @Timaroberts Right, I changed the Focal Length value back to 50 and played with the camera position and it seems to be fine now.

Comment: ??? ... btw it seem to me you would have to go with camera even further

Comment: @vklidu What do you mean ? What else should I do then moving it ?

Comment: Changing your camera's sensor size?

Comment: If you're shooting captions only, and want no 3D / Perspective effects, it would be better through an orthographic camera, adjusting 'Orthographic Scale'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep in mind that Focal Length will change how fish eye distorted or straight-lined your scene looks; it's an artistic tool that distorts or flattens. This example shows how different mm lenses can shape a subject:

[image]
Source https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjbQo.jpg

Also, your scene is full 3D, including the text. You could push the text away from the camera in Z-space or move the camera. OR you could scale the text size smaller.

You can also view "Scene Properties" tab to see and change the units of measure in your scene that the grid corresponds to. This will aid you in making objects at a particular scale if you desire. Some rules of thumb I try to follow: if it has to be a realistic render, then I try to match real-world measurements as close as I can. If it's abstract like text and motion graphics, then I have some wiggle room, but don't go too big or too small and don't go too far from the center of the scene because it just gets difficult to manage. I think larger objects may affect renders because of light photon density... but that's unverified on my end.

Comment: Even I wasn't sure if this was meant to be serious Q you changed my mind :) Great answer. Probably you can extend your A about Orthogonal option.

Comment: It would be useful to show examples of distortion in the context of the question, where there are no human faces but text of straight elements.

Comment: vklidu, thank you, and how did you put the gif into my answer? I could not figure it out. Did it need to be smaller in file size?

Comment: yes, drag&drop up to 2MB (that is why I had to convert to BW) and I agree with susu your example would be much appreciated.